# Application path given by user during application installation

Tags: java, database, sqlite, installation

I am deploying a Java application. User chooses the installation directory of the app. I want to get that path so that i can pass the path for making a sqlite DB der.

Mostly it will be something like :

```
C:\Program Files\My App Name
```

or

```
C:\Program Files(x86)\My App Name
```

The problem is I cannot hardcode the DB location in my code, beacuse i want my application to have the flexibility to be installed on user's choice of path.

Comment: "sqlite DB der" what is that?

Comment: my application has a sqlite Database, i need the database inside the DATA directory of my application installed path. Hope this clear things out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass path dynamically in the run configuration of the Eclipse/IDE

```
-Dfilepath="C:\Program Files\My App Name"
```

Right click on project in the Explorer window --> Run As --> Run Configuration.
Then go to Arguments tab.

**Edit** :
Suppose you get the path of DB from user and then put it in the file **C:\Config\config.txt**. Now this txt file has your actual path where you want to create your db. So through your java program you can read this file and get the path.

Comment: But that path can change according to user's want, how do i get the user's specified path in my application ?

Comment: take input from user and store in a text/properties file. And you can pass file name which should be used to read path.

Comment: but the path will be given during installation, during that time my application will be inactive(i guess). How do i store it.

M newbie to "making installing file from a java project".

Comment: i somehow still dont get it, like i have a project and have created a installation file for it. User will click on the installation file, this will instantiate a process that is different than my project. User will give an address to this process, how do i write it in the properties file of my project ?

Please give me an example if possible